# Injeção de Beans Spring em JAX-WS / Tomcat 7 (@WebServices) - Não funciona, retorna NullPointerException (NPE)

Tags: spring, tomcat, injeção-de-dependência, jax-ws

Gostaria de injetar (`@Autowired` ou `@Resource`) beans criados pelo Spring (`3.x` ou `4.x`) em uma classe que implementa uma interface JAX-WS (implementação de referência).

Testei no Tomcat 6 e funciona, porém no Tomcat 7, parece que a especificação do container mudou e os contextos são diferentes.

Já utilizei a integração proposta (que inclusive tem péssima documentação) como sugerido em: http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-spring-integration-example/

Nesse exemplo, o arquivo `sun-jaxws.xml` é substituído por um arquivo de configuração do Spring. Porém, no meu exemplo estou fazendo tudo com `@Configuration`, pois estava tentando evitar XMLs. Não sei como fazer essa mudança para o Endpoint do JAX-WS conseguir utilizar um bean injetado pelo Spring, sem eu ter que utilizar o `applicationContext.getBean("meuBean")`.

Obs.: Li de tudo, acreditem. Alguns sugerem extender `SpringBeanAutowiringSupport`, outros colocar um `@PostConstructor`, mas nada funciona no Tomcat 7.

É uma definição do container? Não tem como fazer mesmo? Essa é a principal dúvida, para eu desistir de vez. ;)

---

### UPDATE

@utluiz, obrigado pela resposta. Basicamente eu usei o exemplo do Mkyong, porém quero fazer a injeção sem XML e a configuração através da classe java `@Configuration` que eu criei. `Meu web.xml` ficou assim:

org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener

```xml
<!-- Configure ContextLoaderListener to use AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
        instead of the default XmlWebApplicationContext -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
    <param-value>
        org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
    </param-value>
</context-param>
<!-- Configuration locations must consist of one or more comma- or space-delimited
   fully-qualified @Configuration classes. Fully-qualified packages may also be
   specified for component-scanning -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>com.mkyong.ContextConfiguration</param-value>
</context-param>


<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jaxws-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSSpringServlet
    </servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jaxws-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/hello/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

e a minha classe de configuração:

```java
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.mkyong")
@ImportResource({"classpath*:/applicationContext.xml"})
public class ContextConfiguration {

}
```

Porém, o mapeamento dos endpoint ficam nesse xml (applicationContext.xml) da seguinte forma:

```xml
<wss:binding url="/hello">
    <wss:service>
        <ws:service bean="#helloWorldWS"/>
    </wss:service>
</wss:binding>

<!-- Web service methods -->
<bean id="helloWs" class="com.mkyong.ws.HelloWorldWS">
    <property name="helloWorldBo" ref="HelloWorldBo" />
</bean>

<bean id="HelloWorldBo" class="com.mkyong.bo.impl.HelloWorldBoImpl" />
```

Eu gostaria de retirar esse XML, para isso, preciso configurar em java, o trecho `wss:binding` dentro da minha classe `@Configuration`. Isso eu não sei como fazer.

Obs.: Não teria problema utilizar esse XML também, porém queria fazer as injeções via java e não via XML. Mas parece que o spring ignora o applicationContext.xml quando uso a configuração do contexto via java.

Não sei se ficou claro, o caso é que eu não tenho problema com o seguinte trecho ficar no XML:

```xml
<wss:binding url="/hello">
    <wss:service>
        <ws:service bean="#helloWorldWS"/>
    </wss:service>
</wss:binding>
```

Quero apenas retirar as definiçoes dos bean, para poder usar `@Resource`/`@Autowired` e `@Component`.

Comment: Igor, bem-vindo ao [pt.so]! Seria melhor você postar sua configuração. A questão é: ou o *bean* é gerenciado pelo Spring ou não é. Mas o Tomcat 7 deve estar chamando diretamente suas classes, sem passar pelo Spring, portanto nada vai funcionar mesmo. Não sei se alguém vai conseguir ajudar sem ver no seu projeto como as classes são criadas.

Comment: Obrigado utluiz, editei minha pergunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Salve!

Acredito ter a resposta para a sua questão. Espero que ainda seja relevante.

O que acontece é que quem fornece a configuração do JAX-WS não é o Spring e sim a [biblioteca fornecida pelo Java.NET](https://jax-ws-commons.java.net/spring/), mais especificamente esse cara:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons.spring</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxws-spring</artifactId>
    <version>1.9</version>
</dependency>
```

E ao que parece ela ainda não fornece a configuração por classe e sim apenas por `xml`. O que poderia ser feito é decupar a configuração dele e criar você a classe de configuração de definição dos `beans`. Algo como um `@EnableJAXWS` e lá fornecer o suporte para classes clientes configurarem os *endpoints*.

Se for fazer, sugiro começar dando uma olhada na biblioteca `jaxws-spring` e entender a criação dos `beans`. O *namespace* `org.jvnet.jax_ws_commons.spring` é um bom começo.

Se não quiser fazer, mantenha-se com o XML e deixe documentado a sua decisão. Por uma coincidência, essa pergunta também foi feita na versão EN do site: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14538495/how-to-set-up-a-spring-web-service-without-using-any-xml-files. E lá (até então) não tem resposta. :)